# Error Loki distributed with Helm: no private IP address found, and explicit IP not provided

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki, observability

I'm configuring loki-distributed on a kubernetes cluster via helm, but I'm getting the following error:

failed to create memberlist: Failed to get final advertise address: no private IP address found, and explicit IP not provided.
I found only one solution on the internet, which was on a forum about Grafana Tempo, in which I added the following snippet:

```
loki:
   extraMemberlistConfig:
     bind_addr:
       - ${MY_POD_IP}
backend:
   replicas: 2
   persistence:
     size: 1gi
     storageClass: nfs
   extraArgs:
     - -config.expand-env=true
   extraEnv:
     - name: MY_POD_IP
       valueFrom:
         fieldRef:
           fieldPath: status.podIP
```

However this configuration, some requests I get the following error:
"too many unhealthy instances in the ring"

My current custom-values.yaml is:

```
loki:
  auth_enabled: false
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    storageClass: nfs
    size: 2Gi
  limits_config:
    max_global_streams_per_user: 10000
    max_query_series: 10000
    retention_period: 30d
  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: loki
      ruler: test
      admin: test
    type: s3
    s3:
      accessKeyId: lokiaccess
      endpoint: minio.databases.svc.cluster.local
      insecure: true
      s3ForcePathStyle: true
      secretAccessKey: *****
  storage_config:
    boltdb_shipper:
      active_index_directory: /var/loki/index
      cache_location: /var/loki/index_cache
      resync_interval: 5s
      shared_store: s3
    aws:
      s3: http://lokiaccess:******@minio.databases.svc.cluster.local/loki
      s3forcepathstyle: true
write:
  replicas: 2
  persistence:
    size: 1Gi
    storageClass: nfs
backend:
  replicas: 2
  persistence:
    size: 1Gi
    storageClass: nfs
read:
  replicas: 2
  persistence:
    size: 1Gi
    storageClass: nfs
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 30d
monitoring:
  lokiCanary:
    enabled: false
  selfMonitoring:
    enabled: false
test:
  enabled: false
```

Has anyone experienced this and have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the ring members via the API, for example if you do a port forward to loki-gateway, you can open these links on a web browser:

- Check the member list:
  http://localhost:8080/memberlist
- Check the datasource (what Grafana actually does for testing the DS):
  http://localhost:8080/loki/api/v1/labels

If your pods are not in the memberlist, make sure you add the `extraArgs` and `extraEnv` to each `backend`, `write`, `read` block.

Here's the catch: You need at least 2 `write` pods to not get the `"too many unhealthy instances in the ring"`.

Comment: This is good to know! I've had a bit of a hard time stringing together the documentation for Loki, and the min required ring members is not something I found. The error message could be a bit more helpful (surely too many unhealthy != not enough alive)

Comment: Where is this information coming from? Does the minimum of 2 pods apply to other components as well (`backend`, `read`)?

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment; my understanding is that the minimum applies to `read`, `write` and `backend`(not `gateway`) and is based off the `replication_factor` config: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configure/#common
(lowering it to 1 will allow you to have a single replica of each)

Comment: Hi @Nepoxx, I searched for the error message in the code and found out what the docs don't say nor explain.